# What are the technique of preventing redirect to the Dropbox page during login

Tags: javascript, android, redirect, dropbox

Trying to make some sort of mobile application to work with Dropbox.
During authentication process there is a step which require application to open the page on Dropbox to let user login and allow application to access Dropbox resources.

But Dropbox application for Android doesn't redirect anywhere, after you enter your credentials it just connect you to your Dropbox. How do they do this? Any ideas?

My app is Javascript based, and works but I want to have seamless user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dropbox application for Android most likely has access to internal APIs to accomplish this that third party developers / applications cannot access.

Third party apps wanting to integrate with Dropbox need to authenticate / authorize their users via Oauth.

The Dropbox documentation ([step 2 of the authentication process](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#authorize)) clearly states 
that the user needs to choose whether to grant the application the ability to access files on their behalf.

This is a standard step in the OAuth dance.